# too many connection in a single page?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, dao

i have a site in which every page is divided into 3-4 section.

In every section i make a query (I open and close connection,Statement and resultset).

This means that for every page I have 3-4 connections. Every jsp page is "created" and "filled" by a servlet.

My question is: in every single page (whatever it is, jsp or servlet) should i have just one connection (open and closed)?

Now I have 3-4 connections and the relative queries because i created for every "object" the relative DAO class. For example, i have ArtistDAO, NewsDAO, UserDAO etc, and in every class i open and close connection,Statement and resultset.

Comment: The answer is: yes, you should have one connection per page. Or use a connection pool and let it manage connections

Comment: I use a connection pool

Comment: if the page are "filled" by a Servlet I'll just leave all the DB logic in the servlet